# TableView cells are getting empty data when scrolling quickly

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm running a function`(item.getUserBySupporterID(supporter_id: supporter_id))` in `each cell` to make a request in my `view model` for each cell to get a `String` and an `Image` for each cell. If I scroll down fast on my table view, the data at the bottom is not loaded from the requests while some requests return nil. If I scroll slow, the data is loaded fine:
https://gph.is/g/apk3N5O

````
import Foundation
import UIKit



class NotificationVC: Toolbar, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    private var myTableView:UITableView!
    var notifications:[NotificationViewModel] = [] {
        didSet {
            myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    var profile = SessionManager.shared.profile

    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
        addTableView()
        loadNotifications()
    }
    
    func loadNotifications() {
           print("loadNotifications")
           if let user_id = profile?.sub {
               let getNotifications = GETNotificationsByUserID(user_id: user_id)
               getNotifications.getNotifications { notifications in
            self.notifications = notifications.map { notification in
            let ret = NotificationViewModel()
            ret.mainNotification = notification
    
            return ret
         }
         }
        }
      }
    
    
    func addTableView() {
        
        self.myTableView = UITableView()
        
        
        self.myTableView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        self.myTableView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height
        
        self.myTableView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
        
        
        self.myTableView.register(NotificationCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        self.myTableView.dataSource = self
        self.myTableView.delegate = self
        self.myTableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        
        myTableView.delaysContentTouches = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.myTableView)
        
    
        self.myTableView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        
        self.myTableView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        self.myTableView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        self.myTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        self.myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        self.myTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        
        
        myTableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        myTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        
        
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notifications.count
    }

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! NotificationCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.delegate = self

        let item = self.notifications[indexPath.item]
        cell.viewModel = item
        

        return cell
    }
    
    
}


import Foundation
import UIKit

class NotificationCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static var shared = NotificationCell()
    var profile = SessionManager.shared.profile
    var notificationType:String?
    var messageTextViewBtm:NSLayoutConstraint?
    var viewModel: NotificationViewModel? {
            didSet {
                if let item = viewModel {
                    if let notificationMessage = item.mainNotification?.message {
                       if notificationMessage.contains("replied to your comment") {
                           notificationType = "reply"
                       } else if notificationMessage.contains("liked your comment") {
                           notificationType = "likedComment"
                       } else if notificationMessage.contains("started following you") {
                           notificationType = "follow"
                       } else if notificationMessage.contains("liked your post") {
                           notificationType = "likedPost"
                       } else if notificationMessage.contains("commented on your post") {
                           notificationType = "commentedPost"
                       }
                   }
                    
                  if let supporter_id = item.mainNotification?.supporter_id {
                    if item.gotSupporter == false {
                    item.getUserBySupporterID(supporter_id: supporter_id)
                    } else {
                        self.user_image.image = item.supporterImage
                        self.username.text = item.supporterName
                     }
                    
                    item.supporterImageDidSet = { [weak self] in self?.user_image.image = $0 }
                    item.supporterNameDidSet = { [weak self] in self?.username.text = $0 }
                   }
                    
                    
                                   
                
                    
              }
            }
        }
    

    
   
    
    var components:URLComponents = {
        var component = URLComponents()
        component.scheme = "http"
        component.host = "localhost"
        component.port = 8000
        return component
    }()
    
    lazy var username:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.font = label.font.withSize(19)
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var user_image: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        gesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(userImageClicked))
        image.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        return image
    }()
    
    lazy var messageTextView:UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView()
        tv.isScrollEnabled = false
        tv.isEditable = false
        tv.sizeToFit()
        tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        tv.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
        tv.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
        tv.font = UIFont(name: "GillSans", size: 18)
        return tv
    }()
    
    
    
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(username)
        addSubview(user_image)
        addSubview(messageTextView)
        user_imageContraints()
        usernameContraints()
        messageConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    

    
    
    func user_imageContraints() {
        user_image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        user_image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        user_image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        user_image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        user_image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    }
    
    func usernameContraints() {
        username.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        username.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: user_image.topAnchor).isActive = true
        username.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: user_image.trailingAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true
        username.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    }
    
    func messageConstraints() {
        messageTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: username.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        messageTextViewBtm = messageTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        messageTextViewBtm?.isActive = true
        
        messageTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: user_image.trailingAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true
        
        messageTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: post_image.leadingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    }
    
    
  }



import UIKit
import Foundation

class NotificationViewModel {
    var mainNotification: Notifications?
    var imageLoader: DownloadImage?
    var supporterName: String? { didSet { supporterNameDidSet?(supporterName) } }
    var supporterNameDidSet: ((String?)->())?
    var supporterImage: UIImage? = UIImage()  { didSet { supporterImageDidSet?(supporterImage) } }
    var supporterImageDidSet: ((UIImage?)->())?
    var gotSupporter:Bool = false
    
    func getUserBySupporterID(supporter_id:String) {
        GetUsersById(id: supporter_id).getAllPosts { user in
            self.gotSupporter = true
            
            self.imageLoader = DownloadImage()
            self.imageLoader?.imageDidSet = { [weak self] image in
                self?.supporterImage = image
                self?.supporterImageDidSet?(image)
            }
            if let picture = user[0].picture {
                self.imageLoader?.downloadImage(urlString: picture)
            }
            self.supporterName = user[0].username
            self.supporterNameDidSet?(user[0].username)

    }
 }
    
    
    
    
}```
````

Comment: Are you familiar with how cell reuse works in iOS?

Comment: Not exactly. How does reuse affect this exactly?

Comment: As you scroll the system will reuse cells if they have the same identifier. If it started loading something asynchronously and then finishes after it's been reloaded, you will get weird behaviour with content loading in the wrong cells.

Comment: What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a nice idea to fetch cell info from remote source one by one. It seems you need to find a way to get all supporter infos at once and put them in your notifications. After then dispylay your data with comleted data source.

Downloading image for each cell one by one can be ok with caching. Because images are too big things to download at once(and again and again). And this is not good for your customers especially if they are using cellular data with high pricing(Also most of cases users does not scrooll to bottom of your view so downloading an imagee to not even display is not a good idea). But it seems not same for your supporter info. They can be fetched at once. If there are too much notification data or fething too much supporter info at once makes your app slower, You can write a pagination mechanism.